# I am unable to not run php file from codeigniter asset folder?

Tags: php, codeigniter

My directory structure is

```
project_name
--application
--assets
--user_data
```

I have added test.php file in asset directory.
and i entered url: http://domain.com/assets/test.php

It gives me 404 error.

Thanks

Comment: Add some more info and code. How you call the file? Which file you are loading? etc. 404 error means 'file not found', but could be a lot of things.

Comment: Please elaborate the folder structure. Is it for all files ?

Comment: I suggest converting and putting it in your application/library folder and treating it as a library. `$this->load->library('myfile.php'); `

Comment: I wants to run from assets directory only

Comment: Do you have any .htaccess inside your assets folder?

Comment: You need to read the CI folder structure and functionallity. If you call the url: `domain.com/assets/test.php` you are really calling a controller called `assets` with a function called `test`, unless you have a .htaccess file to redirect the request.

Comment: @JP. Aulet i tried it on my local machine it worked for me. I think it should work on live server also.

Comment: Not necessarily @JP.Aulet The usual `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` htaccess rule gives access to existing files. If he has that.

Comment: I have two rules in .htaccess file i.e already
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

Comment: Is the rewrite module working in PHP?

Comment: @jtheman for something I add in the end of the comment: "unless you have a .htaccess file to redirect the request".

Comment: In `.htaccess` file, above two mentioned conditions, add `RewriteCond $1 !^assets/test\.php`.

Comment: @Tpojka Still not working

Comment: My .htaccess conditions are as below:

  RewriteCond $1 !^assets/test\.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]  
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: Is `project_name` root or directory in root?

Comment: Try with adding `RewriteBase /` before any condition and rules in conjuntion with changing `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]` to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]`. Similar to @ccBlaster21895 answer with adding `RewriteBase /` in line after `RewriteEngine On`, but also having `RewriteCond $1 !^assets/test\.php`.